# User accounts for saving form data?

Tags: database, forms, user-registration

I have a handful of forms on my WordPress site that people fill out, sometimes repeatedly.  They can be fairly long, time-consuming forms, so I'm hoping to find a solution where a user's form data can be saved to the forms that they fill out so that they don't have to go through it all again the next time they return to the site.  Does anyone have any experience with something like this?

Comment: There is nothing "WordPress" about this. Just save the form, and load the existing data back into the form when the visitor returns so that it can be edited.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: I can't agree with you in this case. You still have to save this info somewhare (i.e. using `user_meta`) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like so:

1. Allow them to register on your site.
2. Save their forms as WordPress user meta (use [`update_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)).
3. Modify your forms (so they *prefill* themselves with these saved informations). (use [`get_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta))